# Presenting a second form with Jquery UI Dialog and KnockoutJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, knockout.js, mvc-editor-templates

I have a primary form defined and nicely laid out, it does what it needs to do...

```
@{ Html.BeginForm(); }
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
<h2>Properties</h2>
<hr />
@* I want to put some stuff here... *@
<br class="space" />
<div class="clearfix">>
    <button type="submit" data-bind="click: save">
        Save
    </button>
</div>
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

Now, then. This model (or ViewModel, rather) has an `IList<PropertyViewModel>` attached to it.

A `PropertyViewModel` has its own set of validations. They are pretty simple for now, but there is a chance that later there will be more complicated uses for this setup.

I am using `KnockoutJS` for my viewModel consistency. Though I suppose it is fairly irrelevent. I want to display a second form in a `jQuery UI Dialog` and return the result, essentially..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        name: ko.observable(),
        description: ko.observable(),
        properties: ko.observableArray(),

        save: function () {
            alert(ko.toJSON(viewModel));
        },

        includeProperty: function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                width: 500,
                closeText: '',
                resizable: true,
                buttons: {
                    'Submit': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        callback( @* I want the new data to get sent back *@ );
                    },
                    'Cancel': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    function callback(value) {
        alert(ko.toJSON(value)); // (I will push the new property to the viewmodel here)
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

However, I am not really sure how to actually put the `EditorTemplate` into the dialog, moreover I am not sure how to get the data back out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question, but from what I understood what you are trying to do is pass data to the dialog and retrieve data from the dialog. If that is the case then this may be useful:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Here is detailed example on how to use:

[Passing data to a jQuery UI Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394491/passing-data-to-a-jquery-ui-dialog/3458299#3458299)

Comment: No, that is not really what I am trying to do... or if it is, these examples are extremely cryptic. I do not understand any of this. I need to display a second form inside of a dialog, do validation on it, and return the result back to the original form.

Comment: Actually, this might work. I could wrap the form in a partial view and load it into the dialog, and return its data... I'll experiment a bit, thank you. This isn't quite the answer I was looking for, but I'll see if I can take a different approach using it.

Comment: This did not solve my problem, but it did open up some interesting solutions to other problems.

Comment: @Ciel - I would suggest then maybe rephrasing your question so we can help

Comment: Actually, this did inevitably solve it because it showed me some things about dialogs I did not previously understand.