# Changing the color of a table row after closing a window with jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have an instance where a user clicks a table row which opens a jquery dialog. I'd like change the color of this row when the user has closed the window.

I know dialog has a close param which can be a function(), but I am unsure how to reference the TR from that point.

E.G,

```
$("#myPopup").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    close: function(event, ui){

 // I am not sure how to get the TR name at this point.
        $("#TR-ID").css('backgroundColor','red');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Tr5fX/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/szhqU/

If you can flick your code I can take a look but above demo changes color 3 ways, and it should help.

**behaviour** plz click on `forgot` and you will see a dialog pop-ing up. rest feel free to play around

**code**

```
$("#forgot").click(function(e) {
    $("#forgot-dialog").dialog("open");
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#forgot-dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 255,
    width: 300,
    buttons: {
        "Change Table Color": function() {
            $('#hulk').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $('#hulk').css('background-color', 'red');
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function(){
        $('#hulk').css('background-color', 'blue');
    },
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I know how to reference the CSS property. What I need is a way to reference the calling table row's ID.

Comment: @JasonWells No worries `:)` Like this you mean? there will be alert when you close the dialog box: http://jsfiddle.net/BNScP/ **Please note** to get the name attribute you can do this `$('#RowID-Hulk').prop('name')` this will give you table row name.

Comment: Heh, no.. What I mean is I am calling the dialog from a dynamic table. I will not know the ID of the calling row, therefore I cannot make it explicit.

I thought there is a way to reference the calling element through selectors/traversing the DOM but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: @JasonWells Oh in that case use `.on` and bind the click event of your rows and then just pass `$(this)` which will represent your row, can you please use my demo and make a fiddle I might be able to help you out, `:)`

Comment: Ah, I actually am binding it through .on, but my opener looks like this.

$("#myDivName").dialog.("open");, so are you saying to also pass "this"?

Comment: @JasonWells yep nearly, `:)`
 but something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394491/passing-data-to-a-jquery-ui-dialog if you want flick me a demo I will fix it else the link shows how to pass `this`. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. It looks like we can use data. on the dialog, interesting.

Comment: @JasonWells yearp ! ~:)` you can