# Is it possible to pass parameters in JQuery popup box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to pass parameters in JQuery popup box??

there has two file
form.php <--The user will fill in the form like username.
when the form sumbit, it have a JQUERY pop up box to show his username that is the user fill in the form.

THX
My html code

```
<form method="get" onsubmit="return false;">
    First name:<br>
    <input name="firstname" type="text"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="popupfunctioncall();">
</form>
<div class="popup-container">
    <div class="popup-play"></div>
    <div class="pop-popup white_content" id="light">
        <div class="popup-close">
            <span><font size="5">x</font></span>
        </div><?php 
        echo $_GET["firstname"];

        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="black_overlay" id="fade"></div>
</div>
```

MY Css code

```
.black_overlay {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
z-index: 1001;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
opacity: .80;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);}

.white_content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
height: 500px;
width: 600px;
background-color: #ffffff;
z-index: 1002;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 1002;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;}

.popup-close {
position: absolute;
top: -2px;
right: 7px;}
```

My Javascript code

```
function popupfunctioncall(){
    $('#light').fadeIn(600);
    $('#fade').fadeIn(600);
}

    $(document).on('click','.popup-close',function(){
    $('#light').fadeOut(600);
    $('#fade').fadeOut(600);
});
```

Comment: _Is it possible_ Answer is __Yes__. Now don't ask How. For that you need to share some code

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394491/passing-data-to-a-jquery-ui-dialog

Comment: Thx, I shared some code here, thx

Answer (score 0):

Please look below example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function popupfunctioncall(){
alert($('#username').val()+"/"+$('#color_name').val() );// you can user your popup here 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <input type="text" name="color" id="color_name">
    <input type="submit" name="cub" value="submit"onclick="popupfunctioncall()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THX, It is work for use alert function, but....not work in jquery pop up box function..... I upload the code from the topic.

Answer (score 0):

First, you better to set an ID to the font tag inside the popup window like this.

```
<span><font id='content' size="5">x</font></span>
```

Then you can get the input value and set popup content as follow.

```
function popupfunctioncall(){
    var firstname = $("input[name='firstname']").val();
    $('#content').html(firstname);

    $('#light').fadeIn(600);
    $('#fade').fadeIn(600);
}
```

Hope this help.